# How does the density of neutrinos travelling at approximately light speed depend on the scale factor?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, conservation-laws

I am working through Concepts in Thermal physics by Blundell & Blundell. In chapter 25.1, they derive that in the case of a relativistic gas, the density scales not with $a^{-3}$ but with $a^{-4}$ where $a$ is the scale factor. I can imagine this making sense with photons which do not have conservation law attached to them, but how does this work for massive particles travelling at approximately the speed of light such as neutrinos?

Would the density of neutrinos vary with $a^{-3}$, disagreeing with the derivation in Blundell&Blundell or would it vary with $a^{-4}$, violating the conservation of particles?

Answer (score 3):

There are different densities: the energy density $\rho$ and the particle number density $n$. In case of the non-relativistic gas the energy of the particles,
\begin{equation}
E=c\sqrt{m^2c^2+p^2}\simeq mc^2+\frac{p^2}{2m}
\end{equation}
with $\frac{p^2}{2m}$ usually neglected compared to $mc^2$. Because then the contribution for each particle does not depend on $p$ we get that, $\rho=mc^2 n$. However this is no longer true for the relativistic gas. In that case,
\begin{equation}
\rho\sim T^4,\quad n\sim T^3
\end{equation}
with $T\sim \frac{1}{a}$ you get that $\rho\sim a^{-4}$ however $n\sim a^{-3}$. So the conservation laws associated with particle numbers are not violated.